# Twisted IRC Bot threading

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted, irc, bots

I need help with my Twisted IRC Bot. If there is a big text that is called when using some command (ex. !text) - I need to wait for the bot to finish sending that text before it executes other commands.

Is it possible to make !text threaded so it keeps sending the text to the channel while in the same time listening and executing other commands.

Comment: What is stopping you from sending text while doing other things?  You're assuming the answer is to use threads, so you only included enough information in your question for someone to give you a thread-based answer.  Instead, actually describe the behavior you want, explain how you attempted to achieve it (ideally with some code - <http://sscce.org/>), and explain the problem you encountered with that solution.  Then someone might be able to give you a good solution, instead of having to try to somehow fit multithreading into your question.

Comment: I believe that user1428240 want to have the bot handle commands asynchronously, i.e. have it so that a slow command does not lock up the bot.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need to use threading in order to accomplish anything like this.  Sending the text happens almost instantly; Twisted will buffer it for you, and you can go off and do other things.  In the case of IRC in particular, you can set the [`lineRate`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/api/twisted.words.protocols.irc.IRCClient.html) attribute on the client and messages will automatically be throttled to a particular speed (to avoid being flood-kicked, which is what I think you're really asking), without your code having to do anything.